# Filtering rows in df based on values in two different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing two columns.  I want to reduce redundant rows that have *similar* values in *both* columns.

Here is the df --

| RT | mz |
| --- | --- |
| 5.92 | 155.06023 |
| 2.06 | 156.06732 |
| **5.47** | **166.08585** |
| **4.84** | **166.08601** |
| 5.18 | 171.11246 |
| 7.01 | 194.10652 |
| 7.01 | 194.10653 |

Here is the code --

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/.../pilot.xlsx', header=0)

df2=df[0:1]
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if abs(df.mz.iloc[i]-df.mz.iloc[i-1])>0.001 and abs(df.RT.iloc[i]-df.RT.iloc[i-1])>0.1:
        df2=pd.concat([df2,df.iloc[i:i+1]])
df2
```

This results in the following output --

| RT | mz |
| --- | --- |
| 5.92 | 155.06023 |
| 2.06 | 156.06732 |
| **5.47** | **166.08585** |
| 5.18 | 171.11246 |
| 7.01 | 194.10652 |

The fourth row in the original dataframe is removed in the output dataframe (see bolded rows).  I don't want this to happen.  The if statement includes two conditions using the *and* operator.  Given that *both* conditions are not met, shouldn't the fourth row remain in the output table?

I flipped both '>' to '<' in the if statement and was able to create df2 with just the one row that filled *both* conditions (7.01, 194.10653), which I expected.  But I am trying to do the opposite -- remove just that one row resulting in df2 containing all other rows.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you want to remove consecutive rows? or can they be in any position?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to remove rows that contain similar values in both columns no matter if they are consecutive to each other or not.

Comment: then you need to compute all combinations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the consecutive near-duplicates you can use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with a threshold (per column) to compute a mask for [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# identify duplicates
mask = df.diff().abs().lt({'RT': 0.1, 'mz': 0.01}).all(1)

# keep non duplicates
df2 = df[~mask]
```

output:

```
     RT         mz
0  5.92  155.06023
1  2.06  156.06732
2  5.47  166.08585
3  4.84  166.08601
4  5.18  171.11246
5  7.01  194.10652
```

intermediate:

```
df.diff().abs().lt({'RT': 0.1, 'mz': 0.01})

      RT     mz
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False   True <- only one value within threshold
4  False  False
5  False  False
6   True   True <- all within threshold
```

Comment: This works great.  Thank you for your help!  If there is a way to evaluate non-consecutive rows, I would really appreciate that as well.